# Django: Object of type Profile is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model called Order, Profile and Users. In my Order model, i want to access the Profile of the buyer and seller, so i wrote a function in the Order model to get the profile of the buyer and the seller.

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="service_orders")
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="seller")
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="buyer")
    ...

    def seller_profile(self):
        seller_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.seller)
        return seller_profile

    def buyer_profile(self):
        buyer_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.buyer)
        return buyer_profile
```

Now when i add the `seller_profile` and `buyer_profile` in my `OrderSerializer` in `serializer.py`, and try accessing the api endpoint in the browser, it shows the error `Object of type Profile is not JSON serializable`, Do i need to serialize my `Profile` Model or something like that?

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['id','seller', 'buyer', 'buyer_profile', 'seller_profile', ...]
       
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request and request.method=='POST':
            self.Meta.depth = 0
        else:
            self.Meta.depth = 2
```

I dont have any ProfileSeriallizer, do i need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="service_orders")
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="seller")
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="buyer")
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    # Flatten
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        user= representation.pop('user')
        
        for key, value in user.items():
            representation[key] = value

        return representation

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    seller = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    buyer = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['id','seller', 'buyer']

    def get_seller(self, obj):
        return ProfileSerializer(obj.seller.profile).data

    def get_buyer(self, obj):
       return ProfileSerializer(obj.buyer.profile).data

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request and request.method=='POST':
            self.Meta.depth = 0
        else:
            self.Meta.depth = 2
```

Comment: this is not fixing the error, i have added the property method on my method

Comment: My mistake, I did not create the profile. So, yes you are going to need a `serializer`. Also, you do not need the model methods, instead you can access `profile` via relationship. I will update the answer. (I must say that, it would be probably better to use `Profile` directly in the model relation).